# Faker gem - Where is the data being fetched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I'm trying to understand how the Faker rails gem works, so hopefully I can contribute to it. The project is found here: https://github.com/stympy/faker

Under ~/lib/faker/name.rb there will be code like this:

```
def first_name; fetch('name.first_name'); end
```

My problem is I don't understand where the hash with all the "name.first_name" is located.

Comment: Look at the `Base` class, and the localization files, e.g., https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en.yml

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `"def fetch"` shows me that the method is defined in `lib/faker.rb`.

`fetch` in turn calls `translate`, which delegates to `I8n.translate`.